# Combining a filter and a map

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to combine a `map` and a `filter` in a single javascript expression? For example, I am currently doing the following to trim whitespace and remove empty results:

```
const s = "123 hiu 234234"
console.log(s
            .split(/\d+/g)
            .filter((item, i) => item.trim())
            .map((item, i) => item.trim())
            );
```

Is there a more compact way to do that? And, as a follow up question, is the `/g` necessary when doing `split` or does that automatically split every occurrence?

Comment: `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: also, you're correct, you don't need `/g` when using split

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that can replace the longform `filter`, but still it doesn't trim the result.

Comment: no thats `.maps` job, you cant join filter and map, they do different things, filter filters and map loops over and mutates each item in the array, filter cant mutate and map cant filter

Answer (score 0):

that...

```js
const s = "123 hiu 234234"

console.log( s.match(/[a-z]+/ig) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If a single word comes between the numbers, I think a single regular expression would be enough here - just match non-whitespace, non-digits:

```js
const s = "123 hiu 234234"
console.log(s
            .match(/[^\d ]+/g)
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would also be to define a function that takes two arguments that you can call which does the task. For example:

```js
const s = "123 hiu 234234"
const Trim = (item, i) => item.trim();
console.log(s.split(/\d+/).filter(Trim).map(Trim));
```

Or you could put the burden on the regex itself, for example only matching letters:

```js
s="123 hiu 234234"
console.log(s.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g));
                //  /[a-z]+/gi alternately
```